# Не работает AJAX после деплоя на сервер

Tags: javascript, ajax, http2

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть приложение, которое я выложил на бесплатный хостинг и проблема заключается в том, что после публикации перестали работать ajax запросы. Это же приложение запущенное локально у меня на ноутбуке работает корректно.

Например, на этой странице https://alexandr-dera-laravel.000webhostapp.com/employees_tree представлено иерархическое дерево сотрудников, через JQueryUI реализована возможность переподчинения сотрудника после перетаскивания от одного начальника к другому (drag-and-drop), и сохранение изменений производиться через ajax запрос, где я передаю два параметра: 1) id сотрудника; 2) id нового начальника. Сам javascript:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'put',
url: 'change.chief',
data: {
    'employee_id': employee,
    'chief_id': new_chief,
    '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
});
```

Console выдает ошибку ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR. После поиска возможных вариантов решения проблемы сделал чистку кэш и сокетов SPDY в браузере Google Chrome 
(chrome://net-internals/#sockets) после чего сама ошибка исчезла, но проблема осталась.

Просьба помочь в вопросе. Спасибо!

[Описание](https://github.com/alexandrdera/employees#%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-employees) проекта на github и сама страница представления с ошибкой [здесь](https://github.com/alexandrdera/employees/blob/master/resources/views/employees_tree.blade.php).

**P.S. Запросы get и post получается работают, а put и delete которые я использовал нет.**

Comment: А не пробовали put на post заменить? Рядом подгрузка списка вроде работает через post. Кто у вас на сервере? nginx?

Comment: При post запросе выдает ошибку 405.

Comment: Ну на сервере тоже обработчик нужно менять

Comment: Я использую free план хостинга на https://www.000webhost.com/ и прямого доступа к серверу нет( Это означает что я не могу решить эту проблему при текущем плане?

Comment: Ну к коду-то доступ есть? Где-то в роутинге у вас должны быть бинды а-ля `PUT /change.chief`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Т.е. post работает?

Comment: Да, get и post получается работают, а put и delete которые я использовал нет.

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, глядишь, кто-нибудь из экспертов и расскажет почему так)